# INSERT new row or DELETE old row IF it already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-delete, exists

I need to optimize/implement a MYSQL query wich do the following:

I need to store if an user marked an item as seen, and create a SEEN/UNSEEN button, that delete the correspondent row on the database if already exists (is marked as seen) OR insert a new row  if it not (is not marked).

It means, I need a mysql query that do that:

```
    DELETE FROM table WHERE userid = ? AND itemid = ?
```

or that

```
    INSERT INTO table (userid, itemid) VALUES (?,?)
```

depending on if the row already exists or not.

I now it's very easy doing it with php and checking the number of rows of a SELECT before INSERT or DELETE but I would like to doing that all the optimized I can.

Comment: Couldn't you use REPLACE INTO TABLE (userid, itemid) VALUES (?,?)

Comment: @Spartacus38, not he can't. He wants to delete-record-if-it-currently-exists-or-insert-it-if-it-currently-doesnt-exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) to SELECT and DELETE if exists or INSERT. But much easier would just be left the data there and update seen/unseen with [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Yes, I think that's can be the way. I'll try to see if I be able to understand that method and generate a solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to understand the stored procedures but it seems like it's one level over my knowledge, more when I can't find any examples or cases seems to mine. I have to do the procedures or funcions by myself and I don't think I be able to. But thanks for the answer, that's definitely the correct way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third column to store an integer, ad use that value as a "toggle" to switch between seen/unseen through an UPSERT query.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (userid, itemid, seen) VALUES (?,?,0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE seen = ((seen+1) MOD 2);
```

The primary key should be formed by `userid` and `itemid`. The `MOD` operator will make it easy and efficient to implement the seen/unseen behaviour you want.

Comment: I thought that way too, but I don't know if it's would be very optimized, because if a user mark an item as unseen after mark it as seen, the row would stay stored in database, and it would be totally useless.

I think any programmer have to make each program, each app, suposing this gonna have a million users, preparing every line to make the program all eficient and optimized he can. So I think that there have to be another way to do this. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, that's a wrong idea.
The button in UI shouldn't be called "Make seen/unseen". The button in UI must have concrete name, so user will know what he is doing.
So, you will need to make SELECT before displaying a button anyway.
And button click event algorithm should *not* be like this:

```
if not currently_is_seen then mark_as_seen else mark_as_not_seen;
```

Button algorithm should be like this:

```
if current_button_name_is_mark_seen then {
    if not currently_is_seen then mark_as_seen;
} else {
    if currently_is_seen then mark_as_not_seen;
}
```

(It's ok if under some specific conditions button is named "mark seen" althrough it's already marked seen -- button will just do nothing. It's ok if under some specific conditions button is named "mark unseen" althrough it's already marked unseen -- button will just do nothing. But it's *not ok* when button titled "mark seen" or "mark unseen" *does an opposite action instead*.)

To implement

```
if not currently_is_seen then mark_as_seen;
```

and

```
if currently_is_seen then mark_as_not_seen;
```

you can use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (userid, itemid) VALUES (?,?)
```

and

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE userid = ? AND itemid = ?
```

(delete doesn't cause error if record doesn't exists).

Hovewer, if you want to implement the

```
if not currently_is_seen then mark_as_seen else mark_as_not_seen;
```

logic *very much*, you can use [stored routine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html) ([also here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html)).

Comment: Obviously the user always gonna know what's doing (I show it to him with a SELECT as you comment), but I'm refering only to the back-end. About making a function that do what I want in one single query, depending on the user previous actions (mark the item or not). 

But yes, I see that the stored routines can be the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
check the following link

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm

Comment: He needs on-duplicate-key-DELETE, not on-duplicate-key-UPDATE.